# React.Component does not update when array objects change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple reducer that does the following:

```
case ACTION_TYPE.RATE_BEER:
  const { item, rating } = action.data;
  const beers = state.beers.map((mappedBeer) => {
    if (mappedBeer.id === item.id) {
      return {
        ...mappedBeer,
        rating
      }
    } else {
      return mappedBeer;
    }          
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    beers
}
```

Returning the news state, the component does not update. On the contrary, if I do:

```
return {
    ...state,
    beers: null
}
```

the component updates as expected.

This is the initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  beers: null
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: try returning this: `return {  ...mappedBeer, rating: null }` instead of just `mappedBeer`.  Maybe it is trying to merge.

Comment: make sure you are not using PureComponent

Comment: @DavinTryon I've tried but it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @baklazan I'm using a simple react component.

Comment: does the beers array change?

Comment: @baklazan It doesn't. I'm just injecting the rating property into the beer object.

Comment: I see the problem, if you are adding new prop the render change will not catch it. You need to make sure the rating was set already as an empty or something.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1)I assume your display component is not making use of the state.rating - that's why it's not rendering. From your code I assume you were using state.beer.rating.

2)If your initial state beers: null, you can't rate any beers, because there are no beers to rate; you'll be mapping over an empty array. You'll have to check if the beer is not in the beers array.

This should fix it:

```
const initialState = {
  beers: null
}

case ACTION_TYPE.RATE_BEER:
  const { item, rating } = action.data;
  //add logic here to check if item is not in beers, add it to the state.
  if (!state.beers.some(beer => beer.id === item.id))  {
    return {
      ...state,
      beers: [...state.beers, {id: item.id, rating}]
    }
  }
  //here you're checking to update existing beer rating
  const beers = state.beers.map((mappedBeer) => {
    if (mappedBeer.id === item.id) {
      return {
        mappedBeer.rating = rating 
      }
    } else {
      return mappedBeer;
    }          
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    beers
}
```